# How autoload parent PrestaShop classes in codeception?

Tags: php, composer-php, prestashop, autoload, codeception

I have PrestaShop module project under PrestaShop modules folder name mymodule

```
Prestashop
   admin
   classes
   modules
      mymodule - sub project root
```

I want test module using codeception so I install it under mymodule folder.

```
Prestashop
       admin
       classes
       modules
          mymodule - sub project root
             tests
             vendor
             codeception.yml
             composer.json
             ...
```

All PrestaShop modules extends Module class which is under classes folder and use other classes from parent directory.

When I run `codecept run` inside my root project (module) I'm getting error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Module' not found
```

How can I autoload parent classes in codeception so I can run test under mymodule folder ?

Answer (score 0):

There are rules about the file creation in modules, you should take a look at the official documentation, which is clear about this, and basically is, if your folder is called `mymodule`, PrestaShop will try to find the file called `mymodule.php`, and this file should extend the class `Module`, [here the folder structure](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/creation/module-file-structure/).